# File can't be accessed with chromium when running view(reponse) from scrapy shell

Tags: scrapy

I'm following the developer-tools tutorial on scrapy.org:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#topics-developer-tools

At the "The network-tool" section, when running:

scrapy shell "quotes.toscrape.com/scroll"

Inside the terminal, I'm getting this:

```
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: quotetutorial)
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) - [GCC 9.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.2.1, Platform Linux-5.4.0-54-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'quotetutorial',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'quotetutorial.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['quotetutorial.spiders']}
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: a6b7e55ad47ad876
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage']
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-11-24 11:22:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-11-24 11:22:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f4845b32070>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll>
[s]   response   <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f4845b2fe20>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7f4844ea69a0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects 
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

All good so far.

then I run:

view(response)

and I'm getting this in terminal:

```
>>> view(response)
True
```

But in my browser I get:

```
file:///tmp/tmp_ssijiw4.html

Your file couldn’t be accessed
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I've tried finding answers to the issue online without any useful results.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of chromium's limited access inside the file-system:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home

Change your default browser to firefox:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/79305/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser